# Breakpoints in Chrome not working with Sourcemap

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gulp, webpack, breakpoints

This is the most annoying problem. I've run into [this before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337972/sourcemap-generated-from-gulp-not-working-as-expected), however I have the same setup in my webpack config and gulp and I cannot set breakpoints correctly in the Chrome Devtools.

I've deleted my app file and map, re-run `gulp webpack` which auto-generates it again, and it still does not break where I want too in the app :(

[image]

**Webpack config**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_DEV || '0');
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956937/how-to-build-minified-and-uncompressed-bundle-with-webpack

module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        sourceMapFilename: "tickertags.bundle.js.map",
        pathinfo: true,
        path: __dirname,
        filename: PROD ? "tickertags.bundle.min.js" : "tickertags.bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: PROD ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true })
    ] : []
};
```

**Gulp tasks**

```
gulp.task('webpack',['build:html-templates'],function() {
    return gulp.src('entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack( require('./webpack.config.js') ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'));
});

// Development watch /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ☕️⏎→
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/**/**/*.html', ['build:html-templates']).on('change', function(file) {
        var filePath = file.path.split(rootPath);
        process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red(' →→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→   ' +filePath[1]+ '\n'));
    });

    gulp.watch('app/assets/imgs/*.svg').on('change', function(file) {
        var filePath = file.path.split(rootPath);
        process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red(' →→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→   ' +filePath[1]+ '\n'));
    });

    gulp.watch('sass-smacss/sass/**/*.scss', ['app-css']).on('change', function(file) {
        var filePath = file.path.split(rootPath);
        process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red(' →→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→   ' +filePath[1]+ '\n'));
    });

    gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['webpack']).on('change', function(file) {
        var filePath = file.path.split(rootPath);
        process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red(' →→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→   ' +filePath[1]+ '\n'));
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'webpack']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND THE PROBLEMATIC PIECE OF CODE**

```
var alertVolumeUrl = function(ticker, term_id) {
    var url = api.alertsVolume;
    return _.isEmpty(term_id) ? url + ticker : url;
};

function alertsVolume(ticker, params) {  
    var url = alertVolumeUrl(ticker, params.term_id);
    return $http.get(url, {params: params}).then(function(res){
        return res.data.alerts;
});
```

---

I had to rewrite the 2nd function like so:

```
var alertVolumeUrl = function(ticker, term_id) {
    var url = '/app/api/alerts/volume/';
    return _.isEmpty(term_id) ? url + ticker : url;
};

var alertsVolume = function(ticker, params) {
    return $http.get(alertVolumeUrl(ticker, params.term_id), { params: params }).then(function(res){
        return res.data.alerts;
    });
};
```

Note how `alertVolumeUrl` is being used in the 2nd function now.

That for some reason was causing our breakpoints to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Sourcemaps are broken on the current version of Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611328#c21

Once source maps are fixed (the fix is currently in canary), then I'm sure breakpoints with sourcemaps will be fixed as well.

EDIT: Last link was an outdated bug, the one linked above is current.

Comment: Sweet! Good to know :D was wondering why they broke, especially since we haven't updated webpack or gulp in a while and they broke anyways.

Comment: Edit, sorry in my case it had nothing to do with Chrome at all.. posting the answer now.

Comment: Any way to just disable the source maps?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the only solution is to not use sourcemaps with minified code. Either compile your code without minification, or use chrome dev tools's builtin pretty-print feature. The problem is that minification usually compresses multiple lines into a comma expression. Comma expressions are not interpreted as separate statements by the dev tools, thats why you only can put breakpoints on the beginning of code blocks. Sourcemaps just convert back the textual representation of the minified code, but the engine executes them by lines in the minified code.

**EDIT**

See if disabling sourcemaps helps, this is where you find the setting in Chrome:

Open the developer console, press F1, and find the following checkbox

[image]

Comment: Yes my code is not minified, it only gets minified when I run the build for production Gulp task. This is the end of my current source map: `//# sourceMappingURL=tickertags.bundle.js.map`

Comment: It's also possible that webpack produces wrong sourcemaps. I never tried it myself.

Comment: Strange, my settings look nothing like yours :( I have the latest Chrome too

Comment: Are you in the right settings menu? Press f1 when dev tools is open

Comment: Ok yeah I have that enabled... my sourcemaps used to work, sigh... will have to keep digging.

Comment: I still mean to disable it. :D That waz zou will se what kind of code is that. Is it heavily transpiled or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help :( my bundle is not minified... I'll post an example of what it looks like, it's 12,000+ lines